# Recover data from USB turned bootable

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, partition-recovery, file-recovery, recovery

I was trying to downgrade from Windows 11 to Windows 10. I installed the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft and connected a portable external hard drive that I use to save my files, not knowing the process would delete all my content and turn the portable disk into something different. Now the external hard drive no longer says Toshiba (912 GB) but rather appears as ESD-USB (32GB). I don't know how to get it back to how it was, nor how could I get my stuff back.

I have tried to follow some tutorials and have already installed UFS Explorer and GetDataBack, but I have no idea of how to make my old files appear in the scan results. This is what I've gotten:

[image: UFS scan result].

I don't know if I should restore the drive using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0RuJYfI9zA&ab_channel=OfficeSystems) before attempting to run the scans.

Comment: Everything that was overwritten is gone, period. Whatever wasn't overwritten, if anything, *may* eventually be recovered using recovery tools but don't keep your hopes high. Now, what was written isn't that much - you're confusing "FAT32", a file system with some 32GB size but it has nothing to do with it - because the Windows installer is <8GB. If data is really important send it to a professional service.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1758086/705502

Comment: You should not use your Installation USB for data backups. The USB creation process does tell you that it will be overwritten.